# What's the opposite of append in Ruby? <<

Tags: ruby

If `a = 'foo'` I can do `a << 'bar'` and get back `foobar` But say I want to remove `bar`?

I know I can do `a.slice!(3..a.length)` - But damn is that ugly.

So let's `regex` this silly bastard like: `a.gsub!('bar','')` - But is this *the best* method?

**Why can't I just do this?:** `a >> 'bar'` - This would be super-duper!

*So how do you guys do it? What is the fastest method?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I just do this?: a >> 'bar' - This would be super-duper!

Because it's much clearer to use `[]`.

```
a = 'foobar'
a['bar'] = ''
a # 'foo'
```

If you need to match only `bar` at the end, use a regular expression:

```
a = 'barfoobar'
a[/bar$/] = ''
a # 'barfoo'
```

`a >> 'bar'` wouldn't be 'super duper', it would be totally ambiguous. What does `a >> b` mean? Are you popping a character off the end and storing it in `b`, or taking the value of `b` off the end of `a`, or converting both sides to integers and bit-shifting? `<<` denotes *movement*, the characters from the right-hand side are moving to the left. `>>` would suggest to me that characters are moving from left to right, not that I want to remove and discard characters from the left.

The only reason `a << 'foo'` works is because appending to a string is one of the most common things you'll ever do in software.

Comment: Where's this in the docs? That looks easy! Do you have a staples button on your desk? Please press it now. Still `a['bar'] = ''` is kinda ugly.

Comment: What if I want to take out all of the instances of `bar` with the regex? How would that look?

Comment: You would use `gsub`. And "kinda ugly" is pretty subjective. I consider `a >> 'bar'` **hideous**, no language would ever do with that what you suggest.

Comment: In my opinion I think `>>` would be obvious counter-part of `<<`. Think about it like this. Day/Night, Up/Down, Left/Right, <</>>   Just a thought... Writing `a['bar'] = ''` is not "Ruby" pretty. Just my opinion. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: There doesn't have to always be syntactic opposites. There is no reason for this to be inherently desirable. There is nothing obvious about using `>>` to trim characters from the end of a string; no language I've ever heard of uses `>>` in this way. What happens if you do `'foo' >> 'bar'`, and the characters *aren't there to remove*? There's *no sane way* for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of "append", or "push" is generally called "pop". These names come from a stack (a data structure) terminology, and are usable with arrays:

```
ary = ?f, ?o, ?o
suffix = ?b, ?a, ?r
suffix.each &ary.method( :push )
ary #=> ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r"]
ary.pop 3 #=> ["b", "a", "r"]
```

To use push and pop with strings, you have to arrayify them first:

```
str = 'foobar'
# arrayification
ary = str.each_char.to_a
ary.pop( 3 ).join #=> "bar"
str = ary.join #=> foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work in this case, and is not much cleaner than gsub?:

```
a = 'foobar'
a.delete!('bar')
=> "foo"

a = 'foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar'
a.delete!('bar')
=> "foofoofoofoo"
```